# MS outlook rules

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

Suppose A is sending an email to B where B is a group DL & Mr.x is member of B.

Mr. x wants to see emails from A with B in CC Box in folder-1 and emails from A with B in To Box in folder-2

Is there a way to accomplish this please?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no built-in option available in Rules to realize this requirement. If you are familiar with VBA code, you may refer to the discussion in [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d139c44d-2a10-40f2-ad12-3fb957289a64/outlook-rule-apply-for-distribution-grouplist-on-quottoquot-or-quotccquot?forum=outlook) to try accomplish this using script.

An alternative is that you can using Search folder instead. This will not move mails to the particular folder, but you can still have a view of the mails with the email address in To or CC filed. For instance, to "see emails from A with B in CC Box in folder-1", you may consider creating the search folder using the conditions below:

[image]